# On hovering one pseudo element, make the other pseudo element appear?

Tags: css, hover, pseudo-element

I was trying to generate a screen in which utilises the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements, but I'm wondering if such functionality is actually possible.

I have a wrapper div which is wrapped around an input (allowing for `pseudo element`s on this wrapper).

something like:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| +-------------------------------+ |
| |                               | | <-- wrapper div
| +-------------------------------+ <-- input element
+-----------------------------------+
```

However, I was looking to have a pseudo element positioned after the div.

```
+-----------------------------------++-------+
| +-------------------------------+ | |¯¯¯|  |
| |                               | |    /   |
| +-------------------------------+ |   !    |<--pseudo element
+-----------------------------------++-------+
```

I was wanting to be able to hover this pseudo element, and have the other pseudo element appear.

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrap input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrap:after {
  content: "?";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrap:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: tomato;
  opacity:0.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <input placeholder="input element" type="text" />
</div>
```

---

From the above snippet design, is there a way of making the `:before` element change its opacity when i hover only the `:after` element, and not the `wrap` div itself (note: html cannot be changed, hence why this question)?

---

I tried using something like:

```
.wrap:not(input):hover:before{
```

after changing the width of the input to `90%`, but this didn't make a difference

Comment: An interesting case for making pseudo-elements count as simple selectors so one could do something like `.wrap:has(::after:hover)::before`. But alas...

Comment: @BoltClock Is `::after:hover` valid in selectors level 4? If I remember correctly, pseudo-elements cannot have pseudo-classes...

Comment: @Hashem Qolami: It is in level 4. It depends on both the pseudo-element and the pseudo-class - some combinations are possible while others are not. See http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#pseudo-elements, which says "Pseudo-elements are featureless, and so can’t be matched by any other selector. They also do not affect the interpretation of structural pseudo-classes, which are evaluated based solely on real elements. Other pseudo-classes *can* match pseudo-elements, unless otherwise specified."

Comment: Seems like it's back to the drawing board....

Comment: The closest I could manage with this was to set the `pointer-events` of the parent element to `none` and then reset the `:before` to `initial`. You can then use `:hover:after` on the parent and it will be triggered when hovering of the `:before` pseudo element. The downside in this instance is that, for the `input` to be usable, you'll also need to reset its `pointer-events` meaning it will also trigger the parent's `:hover`. Would you be open to using additional markup?

Comment: @Shaggy: html can't be altered, otherwise using an absolutely positioned element would be the answer....

Comment: @jbutler483, I thought that might be the case. Here's a Fiddle of what I managed to achieve, for your reference: http://jsfiddle.net/tbhLquLz/

Comment: @jbutler483 do you consider cross-browser compatibility ? IE < 8 cannot view this.

Comment: @Raptor: I'm lucky enough not to have to support it :)

Comment: IE7 does not support pseudo elements like [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before), `content` as well

Comment: @Raptor: If the OP is using pseudo-elements like :before and :after in their original question you can generally assume they are not interested in supporting IE7 unless they state otherwise.

Comment: @BoltClock understood :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the because pseudo elements are not 'real' elements, it means that the (currently) cannot be used in this way. Instead, using a 'real' element would allow for this, and so I have chosen to use a span element until this feature may or may not be implemented.

The current implementation displays:

```css
input {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
span {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: tomato;
}
span:after {
  content: "A Question Mark";
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  font-size: 16px;
}
span:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="input element" type="text" />
<span>?</span>
```

Much to the disappointment of my beloved pseudo element design.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not exactly what you asked for but until css can select parents (it's comming) you could just add one more html element:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="inner_wrap">
      <input placeholder="input element" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrap input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrap:after {
  content: "?";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.inner_wrap:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: tomato;
  opacity:0.2;
    display:none;
}
.wrap:hover .inner_wrap:before{
    display:block;
}
.wrap .inner_wrap:hover:before{
    display:none;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/0vwn1w9t/