# Add a tooltip to :after image

Tags: html, css

For a `label` marked with `help` class I would like to add an image and a tooltip from the `data-info` attribute, like in the sample:

```css
/*Image after label*/
.help:after {
  content: url('http://goo.gl/vTV35T');
}

/*'data-help' after label*/
.help1:after {
  content: attr(data-help);
}
:after {
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<h5>Label with image after: </h5>
<label class="help" data-help="some info">some label</label>

<h5>Label with text after: </h5>
<label class="help1" data-help="some info">some label</label>

<h5>What I need is a label, after it an image, 
having a tooltip from "data-help" attribute: </h5>
"some label
<img src='http://goo.gl/vTV35T' title='some info' />"
```

**What I need is bellow:**

[image]

This all **without** using a additional `img` tag, but just the "label".

**NB**

Please run the snippet to better understand the question.

Comment: Yes, you can use url **images** in a `content` property.It's perfectly valid and it works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29601511/on-hovering-one-pseudo-element-make-the-other-pseudo-element-appear)

Comment: It's not possible. The tooltips are html things, not css things.

Comment: @Oriol this why I ask on stackoferflow. Please have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after#Tooltips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

having

```
<div class="field" data-help="this is a help tooltip text">
    <label for="myField">Description</label>
    <input id="myField" type="text"/>
</div>
```

Finally resolved with jQuery:

```
$('.field[data-help]')
.each(function () {
    var help = ($(this).attr('data-help'));
    $(this).children('input')
    .after("<img class='help' src='/img/help.gif' title='" + help + "' />");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the closest I could get:

```css
.help {
  display: inline-block; /* Make it a block */
  position: relative; /* Make it the containg block of ::before */
  pointer-events: none; /* Disable :hover */
}
.help:after {
  content: url('http://goo.gl/vTV35T');
  pointer-events: auto; /* Enable :hover */
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.help:hover:before {
  content: attr(data-help); /* Toooltip */
  position: absolute; /* Out of flow */
  left: 100%; /* At the end */
  bottom: 0; /* At the end */
  color: #000;
  background: #ffffe1;
  border: 1px solid;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 2px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;
}
```

```html
<h5>Fake tooltip:</h5>
<label class="help" data-help="some info">some label</label>

<h5>Real tooltip:</h5>
some label
<img src='http://goo.gl/vTV35T' title='some info' />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is closest to what you want:

```css
.help:after {
    content: url(http://www.outblush.com/i/help_question_mark.gif);
}
.help:before {
    position:relative;
    content:attr(data-help);
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: yellow;
    opacity:0;
    top: 2em;
    left: 8em;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.help:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
 <label class="help" data-help="some info">Some label</label>
```

The main disadvantage is that you have to specify the `top` and `left` for the tooptip.  Here is another option:

```css
.help:after {
    content: url(http://www.outblush.com/i/help_question_mark.gif);
}
```

```html
 <label class="help" title="some info">Some label</label>
```

Comment: Okay I'll give it a shot

Comment: some info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after#Tooltips

Comment: The key difference between the MDN info and what you want is the image.  You want to have content in the `after` selector at all times, and for some of that content to be edited on hover.  As far as I know, that is not possible because you cannot have two `:after`s or `:before`s.  Really the best way to do this is to put everything in the HTML and only use the CSS to control what displays and what shows.

Comment: the problem is the text length... "<label class="help" data-help="some info">
    Some label lksdflkjs dlkfj lkjsdflk jsdlfkgj fljh 
</label>"

Comment: maybe some jquery could help?

Comment: It is notoriously difficult to access pseudo selectors with JavaScript because the elements they select are not part of the DOM